# Why is my tweet not appearing, and when might it appear?

Tags: twitter

I signed up to Twitter and tweeted somebody. It has now been 47min since the tweet and I've been checking the profile of the person I've tweeted, but the tweet has not appeared.

What is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tweet will not appear on their profile but in their *mentions* when they login (this will not be visible to you) The tweet's location in "Twitter space" is in your profile

Here I sent a tweet to someone

[image: @Mention to @Drake]

Here is their profile

[image: @Drake's Twitter Profile]

If the user *replied* it would show in their profile

Comment: So are tweets private until replied to?  So any tweet on a profile is going to be either a tweet from somebody else's profile that is retweeted, or a tweet that has been replied to, is that right?

Comment: No, tweets are public. A tweet from a user to another user doesn't push that tweet to the receiver's profile. It remains on the sender's profile. Replying to a tweet is a tweet in itself which means the reply will show up on the receiver end.

Comment: And the dot at the start of a tweet, that's so it appears on the main screen of the sender, right? (rather than the replies screen)?

Comment: @barlop yes that's correct