# Why is Twitter search not finding results?

Tags: twitter

I tweeted something via Twitter and then tried to search for it. The tweet is https://twitter.com/bgoodr2/status/638042917056065536 so I searched for:

```
Allow Intra-PDF document link navigation
```

and that gave nothing (URL was https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=Allow%20Intra-PDF%20document%20link%20navigation&src=typd). I tried searching for:

```
Intra-PDF
```

and received some results (URL was https://twitter.com/search?q=Intra-PDF&src=typd). I then tried to include the "to:" operator:

```
"Intra-PDF" to:dochubapp
```

which gave https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=%22Intra-PDF%22%20to%3Adochubapp&src=typd but my tweet did not show up there.

Is this the same situation as described in the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/31908/14529%20answer) to [Why is my tweet not appearing, and when might it appear?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31907/why-is-my-tweet-not-appearing-and-when-might-it-appear)

If so, then that is puzzling: I would have expected it to show me my own outbound tweets even if they aren't showing up in the feed of the recipient.

Comment: It's probable that it's just not indexed yet.

Comment: Agreed. I'll wait for a few days, and then recheck it.

Comment: Did you try again and did you get the same results?

Comment: Yes, I rechecked and still no search results.

Answer (score 1):

For me at present, https://twitter.com/bgoodr2/status/638042917056065536 returns:

[image]

This https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=Allow%20Intra-PDF%20document%20link%20navigation&src=typd :

[image]

This  https://twitter.com/search?q=Intra-PDF&src=typd :

[image]

and this https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=%22Intra-PDF%22%20to%3Adochubapp&src=typd :

[image]

So all selections seem to work (now?).